# NameError: name 'ChoiceInline' is not defined , inline = [ChoiceInline]

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

So I'm having a problem with my code, the django beginner tutorial on their website. I am pretty new to programming and I looked at a couple of the other NameError posts on here and the either pertained to installing python, or were a lot more complex that my skill level.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Choice, Poll

class ChoiceInline (admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
            (None,      {'fields': ['question']}),
            ('Date Information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
            ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInLine]

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)

NameError: name 'ChoiceInLine' is not defined
```

Now I know I have not defined StackedInline anywhere like its a variable, I just assumed it was a prefabricated module that calls a django process from somewhere. Where did I mess up? Excuse the extreme newbiness.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Comment: It can definitely be reproduced, because I just ran into the same problem. It's the result of a hard-to-see typographical error in the django tutorial, which the accepted answer remedies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python variable names are case-sensitive.

Replace:

```
inlines = [ChoiceInLine]
```

with (watch `L`=>`l`):

```
inlines = [ChoiceInline]
```